# <body> with certain width and color

Tags: html, css, width, background-color

I've got a little problem for you!
So, i am trying to make a document's body with certain size and background color. But those rules are implementing to a whole document instead of body selector. What's the problem here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Использование стилей: float</title>
<style type="text/css">
 
body{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: silver;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 0; 
}

   
  
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div>This is some text</div>   


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: define background color like - html {background:white;}

Comment: The `body` is the whole document, so to speak. So your whole site get the background color. Change your selector from `body` to `div` and you have your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: silver;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 0;  
}
```

i think u meant to use it on the div and not on the body

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the `<div>` for that. 
The `<body>` tag defines the document's body.
The  element contains all the contents of an HTML document, such as text, hyperlinks, images, tables, lists, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            #someDiv {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                background: silver;
                border: 1px solid red;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='someDiv'>This is some text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to style one `div`, not the whole `body` tag.

I suppose that's the effect you'd like to obtain:

```css
.main-container{
max-width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: silver;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 0 auto;  
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

This is some text

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a div with height and width according to your need and apply css to it, rather than applying to body as body is your whole document.